# SQL Conditional join using different join types and external parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Despite looking at related conditional join questions, I haven't been able to do the following.

I have table `t` with columns `ID` and `Value`, and an external parameter `@Option`.

If `@Option = 'a'` I would like to join onto table `a` which has columns `ID` and `Flag`, where `Flag` is Y/N.

If `@Option = 'b'` I would like to join onto table `b` which just has an `ID` column, and the existence of a matching ID indicates that `Flag='Y'`.

So what I want is something like

```
IF @Option = 'a'

SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,a.Flag
FROM t
INNER JOIN a 
  ON t.ID = a.ID

ELSE IF @Option = 'b'

SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Flag
FROM t
LEFT JOIN b 
  ON t.ID = b.ID
```

but I'm not sure how to set up the equivalent of the `IF` statements.

How can I achieve this?

One unpreferred solution is to ignore the external parameter and return two flag columns, such as:

```
SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,CASE WHEN a.Flag IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE a.Flag END AS aFlag
  ,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS bFlag
FROM t
LEFT JOIN a
  ON t.ID = a.ID 
LEFT JOIN b
  ON t.ID = b.ID
```

but I would really prefer to have just the one column, plus this query is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use union

```
SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,a.Flag
FROM t
INNER JOIN a 
  ON t.ID = a.ID
where @Option = 'a'

union all 

SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Flag
FROM t
LEFT JOIN b 
  ON t.ID = b.ID
where @Option = 'b'
```

Comment: This does what I'm after, although is fairly slow as it has to query both tables. Is there a faster way, such as making it only query the table it will use (based on `@Option`)?

Comment: technically, it doesnt query both tables as the where condition should be evaluated as a impossible solution in one case.

Comment: Testing today, the speed issue isn't present anymore. Not sure why the change. Accepting this answer as it works and I think is clearer than the nested CASE statements of Rokuto's answer (which also works and at comparable speeds).

Answer (score 1):

You can also include checking value of parameter `@Operation` in `JOIN` and `CASE`.

```
SELECT 
  t.ID
  ,t.Value
  ,CASE 
      WHEN @Operation = 'a' THEN 
                              CASE WHEN a.Flag IS NULL 
                                 THEN 'N' ELSE a.Flag 
                              END 
   WHEN @Operation = 'b'THEN 
                              CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL 
                                 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' 
                              END 
   END AS Flag

FROM t
LEFT JOIN a
  ON t.ID = a.ID AND @Operation = 'a'
LEFT JOIN b
  ON t.ID = b.ID AND @Operation = 'b'
```

In your first query, you are joining to table `a` with `INNER JOIN`, so if you want to simulate this, you can add `WHERE` as follow:

```
WHERE @Operation = 'b' OR (@Operation = 'a' AND a.Id IS NOT NULL)
```